# Происхождение слова "шаромыга"

Tags: этимология

Шаромыга - это мошенник, проходимец. А вот откуда взялось это слово? И связано ли оно со словом "шара" (халява)?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Помнишь, какъ мы съ тобой бѣдствовали, обѣдали наширомыжку...» (Н.В. Гоголь. "Ревизор").

В русском  языке слово  «шаромыга» известно с 1-ой половины 19 века, а выражения «шаромыжник, шаромыжничать» употребляет в своих письмах Пушкин и Вяземский.В словарях отмечается с 1852 года в качестве диалектного слова со значением "любящий всё даровое, пустой, ветреный человек, также мот, пьяница, обманщик".

Наиболее убедительной версией является происхождение слова «шаромыга» от выражений шАром-дАром (первоначально арготического) и шармА, то есть «ни за что, без всякой затраты».  При образовании использовался суффикс -ыга, который "часто дает презрительный оттенок: забулдыга, мотыга, торопыга, коротыга, сквалыга.

Версия о происхождении слово от cher ami (любезный друг) не считается убедительной. Имеется в виду, что французы в 1812 году, изнуренные холодом и голодом, таким образом обращались к  своим победителям, солдатам и крестьянам, умоляя их о помощи, а часто и о пощаде.

Answer (score 0):

Французы во время бегства1812из Москвы побираясь по деревням обращались ко всем у кого могли чем либо поживиться "шероми,и от этого пошло, вон опять шаромыжничиют, то есть попрошайничают

Answer (score 0):

**Шерше** ля фам - ищите женщину, французский. **Шарить, шариться** - искать.(не стоит с путать с шарить от to share(англ.) -  делиться.)

> Калиф, не говоря ни слова более, сам стал **шарить** в траве. Крылов. 17-какой-то.

> Ты думаешь, што я не чувствовал, как ты ночью около меня **шарился**. Ф. М. Решетников. Где лучше? (1868)
> Шаромыга. - думаю метаморф от шарить и шмыгать.

**Шмыгать** - быстро проскальзывать сквозь препятствие к цели поиска, суетиться, мельтешить. Мигать - мельтешить.

> Вот, бывало, коли кто виноват, так и скажут: с той стороны не проси вот этого, а с этой этогo; а потом (держа в одной руке карты, одним пальцем **шмыгает**, между тем Советник остановляет игру в шахматы и смотрит на нее с нежностию) тот и выглядывает карточку; а там до этой карты и пойдет за всякую дранье; там розно: краля по щеке, холоп за ухо волок. Д. И. Фонвизин. Бригадир (1783-1786)

> — Всё, вишь, дочь его мимо наших окошек **шмыгает** да в кухню к нам часто заглядывает. Гончаров.

> двери лавок устают затворяться и отворяться; узлы, кульки, тюки, ящики ежеминутно шмыгают то с возов, то на воза... Кокорев.

> Чиновники между тем, как шмели, беспрестанно шмыгали мимо него.

**Шаромыга, шаромыжник** - суетливый плутоватый любитель поживиться за чужой счет или тем, что плохо лежит, мелкий жулик, мелочный воришка, побирушка. Образовано, видимо, через соединения шарить и шмыгать.

> Другую пристяжную привел, наконец, сам извозчик, седенький, сгорбленный старичишка, и принялся ее припутывать. Между тем старый извозчик, в ожидании на водку, стоял уже без шапки и обратился сначала к купцу. — Мелких, любезный, нет, — отвечал тот равнодушнейшим тоном. — И мелких не стало, — повторил извозчик, почесывая в голове, — купечество тоже, **шаромыжники**! — прибавил он почти вслух, обходя тарантас и обращаясь к Калиновичу. А. Ф. Писемский. Тысяча душ (1858)

> — Так точно, я лучше домой-с. Хоть пяти копеек нет ли у вас? Вы даете. Особа мгновенно юркнула в тьму, и скоро издали вы слышите такое приветствие: — **Шаромыжник**! Подавись ты своим пятаком! Г. И. Успенский. Побирушки (1865)